# Spring Cloud Dataflow REST API: deploying Spring Batch-specific REST API and Console standalone?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I need a Spring Batch Admin-like application to embed in my own SB-powered Spring Boot application.

The Spring website says it's deprecated and been moved to the Spring Attic.  They recommend making use of Spring Cloud Dataflow Console.

I investigated this, and it appears that there is a lot of additional functionality I don't need -- all I want to do is inspect and retry batch job executions.

Is there a means of getting *only* this functionality, short of carving out the Jobs controllers out of the REST API implementation, and building my own admin screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; however, you'd *still* have to use SCDF to gain access to the REST-APIs.

Once when you have SCDF running, you'd get access to the [Task/Batch-job](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources) specific REST endpoints and that you can use in your custom dashboard tooling.